# Esper EPL statement each time a value has increased a multiple

Tags: esper, epl

I am looking for an EPL statement which fires an event each time a certain value has increased by a specified amount, with any number of events in between, for example:
Considering a stream, which continuously provides new prices.
I want to get a notification, e.g. if the price is greater than the first price + 100. Something like

```
select * from pattern[a=StockTick -> every b=StockTick(b.price>=a.price+100)];
```

But how to realize that I get the next event(s), if the increase is >= 200, >=300 and so forth?

Diverse tests with context and windows has not been successful so far, so I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The contexts would be the right way to go.
You could start by defining a start event like this:

```
create schema StartEvent(threshold int);
```

And then have context that uses the start event:

```
create context ThresholdContext inititiated by StartEvent as se
     terminated after 5 years

context ThresholdContext select * from pattern[a=StockTick -> every b=StockTick(b.price>=context.se.threshold)];
```

You can generate the StartEvent using "insert into" from the same pattern (probably want to remove the "every") or have the listener send in a StartEvent or declare another pattern that fires just once for creating a StartEvent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it is still not exactly clear to me. Consider the following values for prices - the event should always fire, where an x is:
0 StartEvent
30
99
100 X
101
103
130
199
200 X
201
260
301 X

Comment: context ThresholdContext insert into StartEvent select a.price + 100 as price from pattern[a=StockTick -> b=StockTick(b.price>=context.se.threshold)]  // i.e. when pattern matches use the price of "a" and add 100 and make that a new start event, also change the "terminated by" if needed